# Webpage that doesn't overflow and has a 100% Height/Width

Tags: html, css

as I stated in the title I'm trying to make a website were you can not scroll down or something, it should cover the whole webpage.

Here is an example,
[image]

I tried doing this but whenever I set the height and width to 100% it doesn't seem to work, it always make content inside the wrapper that exceeds 100% overflow.

Edit: also making everything equal to 100% height/width doesn't work since I'm using borders and px.

Comment: Please post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the flexbox sticky footer technique. The 100vh makes it always the height of the screen and then flexbox magic takes care of the rest making it always fit no matter what screensize. Check it out:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main class="content">
        <section class="left-side"></section>
        <section class="right-side"></section>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
}

header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}

main.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.left-side, .right-side {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: orange;
}

footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Full codepen example: http://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/zZXXWy

Comment: Sorry try link again

Comment: @MartijnEbbens It looks like the entire Codepen site is broken for you, not StefanBob's code. It loads normally for me. However, StefanBob, can you include your entire answer here in a Stack Snippet instead of relying on a 3rd party site?

Comment: Yea true, sure one sec

Comment: Sorry, it's my virus scanner blocking some HTTPS sites (using sha).

Comment: Alright, this seem to be working just fine! I'll accept this as a answer. (Works with borders too!)

Comment: It seems to be putting everything in the center, all divs in the main are centered, how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Have to add a middle section sorry. I think this is what you are asking? Check the codepen again

Answer (score 2):

use

```
body{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

(don't forget to use a reset sheet first)

If you use `px`(usage that I don't recommend), you may use the CSS `calc()` function for sizing things just like this (for instance) `width: calc((100vw - 900px) / 2)`

EDIT

For everything else :

CSS

```
div#header/*or simply the HTML header*/{
  width:100vw;
  height:/*something here that I'll call Hh for calculuses (less than 100vh)*/;
  float:left;
}

div.sidebar{
  width:/*something i'll call SBw for calculuses (less than 50vw)*/;
  height:calc(100vh - Hh - Fh);
}

div#main{
  width:calc(100vw - SBw - SBw);
  height:calc(100vh - Hh - Fh);
}

div#footer/*or simply the HTML footer*/{
  width:100vw;
  height:/*something I'll call Fh*/;
}
```

and HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div class="sidebar" id="Sidebar1"></div>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <div class="sidebar" id="Sidebar2"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sometimes I just have to use pixels, percentages don't always work, but is this really the best way to do this? I should be able to do this automatically in someway without keep having to think if it equals a 100 percent.

Comment: Use `vw`and `vh` those are reliable for responsive.